# Dart null variable creation

Tags: flutter, dart

I just started learning Dart. There is some problem when I am creating a null variable. When I type

> String someVar;

it throws an error but when i type

> dynamic someVar;

it doesn't. I tried doing alternative methods mentioned in Dart's doc but even those methods do not seem to work until i have a dynamic var type. Can anyone tell me what is it?

Comment: "it throws an error but when i type" what error it throws ? You should understand from that error itself. You can search for NULL SAFETY in dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart has a feature called null safety, so when you define something which might have a null value, you have to use `?`.

In your code above, try something like `String? somevar;`

If you are going to initialize the variable later, then define `late String somevar;`

Answer (score 0):

If you have null safety on `String someVar;` will give you an error because it cannot be null.
If u want a variable to be a nullable string, use `String? someVar`.

Try avoiding the use of `dynamic` because it will allow for the type to not be fixed. This can potentially cause the accidental assigning of a value with a type you are not expecting.

Comment: Thank you for the input and also the advice, I will definitely keep that in mind.